# Button won't open new component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm learning React and I'm having issues opening a new component that I created. On my page I have a button to create a new record and when clicked the URL changes but the component doesn't render.

Note: I am able to open existing components within the app, just not newly created new ones.

The code looks like:

```
<div>
    <NavLink className="btn blue" to="./CreateNewUser">Add New User</NavLink>
</div>
```

the component:
CreateNewUser.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class CreateNewUser extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>Add New User</h2>;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `to` is referencing the path to a component while it should reference an arbitrary route string that your app handles.

Comment: It also looks like you're using `NavLink` while the React Router documentation for React Native documents a [`Link` component](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Link). Though we can't be sure since the question should include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely missing the route to your new component in react-router.

You can check the sample code in [this link](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/classes/react-router-dom/NavLink) for reference, specifically the `<Switch>` tag and the `<Route>` tags within it

Comment: So, I have to add the <Switch><Route path....> to every page that has a button, link, etc. to it for it work?

Comment: @CSharpCoder Not on every page that has a link or button, but the routes should be defined somewhere, see the [basic example to get started](https://reactrouter.com/native/example/Basic).

Comment: @EmileBergeron, thanks I'll take a look. So is it possible to just have a JS file that has nothing but my nav information in it and just import it to the App.js file?